# Import and show a model from a WRL file in Android application

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I need to import and show a 3D model from a [WRL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML) file in Android application. So far I have not been able to find any API examples' or 3rd party libraries to help with this. Any ideas (other than converting to another 3D file format)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems at present that no libraries are available for importing a WRL file into a native Android application. The solution is to convert the file to a 3DS or OBJ file format and then make use of the min3D framework.

Answer (score 2):

min3d is a promising one http://code.google.com/p/min3d/ 
hope this is what you need

Comment: Yes, I agree, but as far as I could see they do not support wrl files (yet). Have I missed their code example for importing wrl files?

Comment: From a quick scan I'm not seeing anything in that library that I would classify as a VRML parser/renderer.  Where is that functionality?

Comment: i was thinking since wrl files are made with the World Wide Web in mind, there must be an easy way to do it using webview